# how to get data from json file using name in url in react?

Tags: reactjs, url, axios, fetch-api, urlfetch

```
db.json
{
  "Blogs":
   [
     {
      "title": "My first Blog",
      "body" : "Lorem a qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
      "auther": "mario",
      "id":1
     },
     {
       "title": "My New Website blog",
       "body" : "Lorema qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. ",
       "auther": "john",
       "id":2
     },
     {
       "title": "My New Website blog",
       "body" : "Lorema qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. ",
       "auther": "john",
       "id":3
     }
   ]
}
```

from this database I want to show only author John blogs on John blogs page . I want to use his name in url or when I clicks on john blog then only John blogs should be seen.
Through ID it is accessible but only one blog.

```
const {id} = useParams();
  const {data:blogs,isPending,error} = useFetch('http://localhost:8000/blogs/' +id );
```

`useFetch` is a hook.
This works good but when blog/ +auther it didn't work

```
const {auther} = useParams();
  const {data:blogs,isPending,error} = useFetch('http://localhost:8000/blogs/' +auther );


database respond error:
> XHRGEThttp://localhost:8000/blogs/john [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 48ms]
. 
console.log(res) show error this
 XHRGEThttp://localhost:8000/blogs/john
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 48ms]
'
import{ useState , useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const useFetch = (url) => {
console.log(url);
  const [data,setData] = useState(null);
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect( ()=>
  {

    setTimeout (()=>{

    axios.get(url)

         .then(res => {
           console.log(res);
           const persons = res.data;
           setData(persons);
           setIsPending(false);
           setError(null);

         })
         .catch((err)=>{
           setIsPending(false);
           setError(err.message);
         })

   },1000);
 },[url]);

return { data, isPending, error }
}
export default useFetch;
```

Is is possible to fetch data from database by name or title? Please explain briefly, I'm new at react. Thanks.